# Visualizar resultado de forEach fora dele

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Há alguma forma dos dados do `forEach` ser visualizado fora do `forEach`?

Preciso visualizar os dados do `forEach` fora dele, mas sempre que faço isso ele só devolve o último dado, e não todos os dados. Já tentei utilizar o `localStorage` e da o mesmo resultado.

Se caso não dê, tem alguma forma de fazer um `forEach` com dois arrays? Poderiam dar exemplos?

Meu código:

```
this.MetaService.CheckOrderGet().subscribe(
              data => {
                const pesquisa = (data as any)
                this.check = JSON.parse(pesquisa._body)            


                this.check.forEach(apielement => {

                  this.fil.forEach(dados=> {            


                    if (apielement.FI == dados.FI) {
                      console.log(`Dados iguais ${apielement.FI}`);                      
                    }else{
                      console.log(`Diferentes ${apielement.FI}`);

                    }

                  })                
              }
            )
```

Comment: não pode por um exemplo prático para ajuda a entender? o `forEach` nada mais faz que verificar os elementos de um array, você pode inspecionar esse array a qualquer momento, em outras partes do código. *"le só devolve o ultimo dado, e não todos os dados"*, sim, a cada interação um elemento é acessado, quando acaba só tem referência ao último, a não ser que você guarde vários elementos... *"tem alguma forma de fazer um forEach com dois arrays?"* não, o forEach é para um objeto (array, collection) por vez, mas pode fazer um dentro do outro se quiser

Comment: Eu fiz um dentro do outro, mas aí eu precisava fazer a comparação do resultado de um com o outro, e nisso os resultados acabavam sendo repetidos, aí a comparação nao tinha o resultador correto. Vou colocar o meu código pra ajudar

Comment: @Maria aqui nao rola usar um for e navegar no outro array pelo indice nao? tem alguma chance dos array A ser diferente do B?

Comment: outra coisa se vc for array[indice][subindice].obj vc navega por ele fora do for each

Comment: é que eu preciso de um dado especifico que ta dentro deles, pra poder comparar um com o outro. Preciso percorrer o array pra acessar só um dado dele @Willian

Comment: Praticamente quase sempre os arrays vao ser diferentes e também vai ter igual sempre

Answer (score 1):

Não entendi muito bem sua dúvida, mas essa função aqui faz a comparação entre os dois arrays, linha a linha, verificando os dados em cada posição se são iguais ou diferentes. Começa varrendo o primeiro array e percorre o segundo array comparando os indices.

```
const a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
const b = [5, 4, 3, 1, 2, 5, 6];

a.forEach(function(valor){
    b.forEach(function(v) {
        if(v === valor)
            console.log('iguais');
        else
            console.log('diferentes');
    });
});
```

Comment: Não tem como ele mostrar uma unica vez os diferentes e iguais? Pq ele mostra os diferentes nos iguais, e só no final ele mostra quais sao realmente iguais e diferentes

Answer (score 0):

```
this.MetaService.CheckOrderGet().subscribe(
data => {
const pesquisa = (data as any)
this.check = JSON.parse(pesquisa._body)            

this.new = [];
for (var key in this.check) {
  if (this.check[key].FI == this.fil[key].FI){
   this.new[] = `Dados iguais ${this.check[key].FI}`;
  }else{
  this.new[] = `Diferentes ${this.check[key].FI}`;
  }
}

);
```

o new vai estar fora do forech

Comment: axo que tem em ema6 ou 7 o foreach de key value, transcreve ae se precisar

Comment: ta dando erro no  `this.new[] =` que fica dentro do if

Comment: `Dados iguais ${this.check[key].FI}`;

Comment: Com this.check dá erro, eu tive que colocar `Dados iguais ${apielement.FI}`;

Comment: o código ficou assim `this.check.forEach(apielement => {

                  this.fil.forEach(dados => {


                    for (var key in apielement) {

                      console.log(this.new);
                      
                      if (apielement[key].FI == dados[key].FI) {
                        this.new = `Dados iguais ${apielement.FI}`;
                      } else {
                        this.new = `Diferentes ${apielement.FI}`;
                      }

                    }`

Comment: editei a resposta ae seria assim pelo que descreveu

Comment: isso dentro do forech? ele ta mostrando apenas os iguais, tem como ele mostrar os diferentes?

Comment: entao mais como que esta a estrutura vindo do backend? pq olhando daki parece que o codigo esta separando, me passa os dados do backend ou da uma analisada com um console.log(this.check[key].FI, this.fil[key].FI); abaixo do for e antes do if

Comment: me passa o array que tem do back end dos 2 array que teste aqui

Comment: os dados do this.fil vem de uma api, e os dados do this.check vem de outra api. pq quando os dados do this.check nao tiver no this.fil, ele deve ser inserido lá, e caso ja esteja, ele faz nada

Comment: array do this.check =`[
    {
      "FI": "24",
      "porc": "92,509%"
    },
    {
      "FI": "36",
      "porc": "51,445%"
    }
  ]`
array do this.fil = `(8) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {FI: "15", porc: "167,701%"}
1: {FI: "02", porc: "138,763%"}
2: {FI: "33", porc: "110,720%"}
3: {FI: "30", porc: "103,536%"}
4: {FI: "24", porc: "100,733%"}
5: {FI: "04", porc: "96,082%"}
6: {FI: "03", porc: "84,180%"}
7: {FI: "20", porc: "75,897%"}`

Comment: da uma olhada ae rodou de boa https://ideone.com/L1dnQN

Comment: como n? igual: 24,diferente: 39,igual: 36, ae ve se e isso igual: 24 , 24,diferente: 39 , 37,igual: 36 , 36... olha la dinovo o ideone

Comment: no código aqui ficou assim: `    var neww = [];
                for (var key in this.check) {
                  if (this.check[key].FI == this.fil[key].FI) {
                    neww.push('igual: ' + this.check[key].FI);
                  } else {
                    neww.push('diferente: ' + this.check[key].FI);
                  }
                }
                
                console.log(neww);` certo? mas aí ele mostra no console só os diferentes, que na vdd os dados q ta mostrando nao ta correto, sao os dados iguais

Comment: ah vei;;; vc joga wow de troll ne... claro o console.log so ta no diferente... ponhe um no igual pra ver

Comment: acabei mostrando o código com um teste q eu tava fazendo, o correto é `       var neww = [];
                for (var key in this.check) {
                  if (this.check[key].FI == this.fil[key].FI) {
                    neww.push('igual: ' + this.check[key].FI);                                                                        
                  } else {
                    neww.push('diferente: ' + this.check[key].FI);
                    
                  }
                }                
                console.log(neww);`

Comment: conseguiu @Maria? seguinte essa função que fiz ela verifica o array por posição caso os array não estiver igual, e melhor usar a do @JrD, pois ele vai fazer um loop em cada posição do array 2